# By Genesis 1:9 .and Genesis 1:10.Don't we have separation of the water into (e.g.) particular oceans and/or rivers?

Tags: genesis, creation

In Genesis, it is said in the early days or at the time of creation When Gd created or was creating the world he ordered the appearance of land on one side and water (all in one) on the other. Does this mean w
e didn't have demarcations between these waters such that we have land forming their river

Comment: The text does not indicate 'land on one side' and 'sea on the other side'. It is an overall description of the existence of land and the existence of sea, as such. I think you have an image in your mind which the text does not imply.

Comment: I agree with @Nigel J.  Perhaps it would be better to sharpen the question a little.

Answer (score -1):

This is my expertise. The Bible does not reflect modern science. The Bible reflects the Message and the messages from God through authors that lived in the ancient Near East and within a greco-roman worldview. Genesis 1-2 is not a retelling of how God created and ordered matter from a modern perspective. Genesis 1-11, specifically yet not exclusively, describes how God created life, how divine being corruption and human corruption started and increased as time went on, how God flooded the world--which is textually global but might scientifically only be regional--and how the nations dispersed after Babel even though the Table of Nations is in Gen 10.

Therefore, to answer your question, Gen 1.9-10 is about a primeval hill or mound appearing as the waters gathered in one place around that primeval hill or mound. There is neither nothing about "one side" or "the other," nor anything about "demarcations." It's an ancient Near Eastern way to retelling in a very unscientific and generic way that there was a primeval mound or hillock that appeared.

If you want more information, please google "genesis primeval mound, hill, hillock." You will find a lot of scholarly articles and books on this matter.